# Problem with number of stars showing at the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with Rails and trying to make a page which can show some stars at the bottom of the page as you can see in the picture [picture about number of stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFa7G.png).

Then, to do that, I made the file named form.html.erb and here is the code

```
<%= form_with(model: course) do |form| %>
<% if course.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(course.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this course from being 
saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% course.errors.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :image %>
<%= form.text_field :image, placeholder: "Image" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :video %>
<%= form.text_field :video, placeholder: "Video" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :title %>
<%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :star %>
<%= form.text_field :star, placeholder: "star" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :description %>
<%= form.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description", length: "800", class: 
"materialize-textarea"   %>
</div>
<button class ="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
<%=link_to "Go to all courses", courses_path, class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

To show the star at the page, I made the file named show.html.erb, and I wrote some code like this

```
<span class="card-title"><%= @course.title %></span>
<% (1..4).each do %>
<% (1..@course.star).each do %>
```

And at my home.html.erb, I wrote some code like this

```
<div class="card-content">
  <span class="card-title"><%= course.title %></span>
  <% (1..course.star).each do %>
  <i class="material-icons green-text">grade</i>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

At the input of the course, I input 2 at the star, but it do not display 2 stars but as you can see as my attached picture, it display many stars. I am very confusing with this problem.

Could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem must be solved by now.
Still, I think the code you have written in show.html.erb is responsible for many stars

You said your input was 2 and it's showing many stars, so maybe they are getting displayed multiple times(4 times to be accurate).

Remove this line from show.html.erb
`<% (1..4).each do %>`

I think that's the problem